# NLP for classifying a YES or NO response to a question

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, text-classification, topic-model

I'm currently working on a project that requires some feature extraction. The data I have is text and comes from an interview. The interviewer asks a question, the client responds, and the interviewer collects the response.

Examples:
How much of *this* do you do?
I do *this* sometimes, maybe twice a week.
Returns: True

How much of *this* do you do?
N/A
Returns: False

How much of *this* do you do?
I've been trying to stop recently.
Returns: True

How much of *this* do you do?
I haven't done this in a long time. I used to when I was younger.
Returns: False

I've done some research into LDA and think this could be a good fit, but what I've gathered is that it predicts the general topic, not whether someone answers a specific way.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like that the word, "you", is in the question to machine. Would you elaborate "specific way"? Do you want trained language model has certain characteristic?  If yes, I think you could train with specific dataset such as one person's diary.